# How to use agglometative clustering with 1 dimensional array valueset?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I have around 7k samples and 11 features which I concentrated into one. This concentrated value I call ResVal and is a weighted sum of previous features. Then I gathered these ResVals into 1D array.

Now I want to cluster this results with AgglomerativeClustering but console complains about 1D array.

How can I fix it and get cluster results by line number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array into a column: use `x[:, np.newaxis]` instead of `x`